# Fazer update no banco ao clicar em objeto sem refresh

Tags: programação-estruturada

É o seguinte galera tenho uma tabela de dados como vocês podem ver abaixo, nela tem o ícone de um olho, do qual quando clicado faz um direcionamento para uma outra pagina passando o "id" do arquivo via url e dando um update na linha do arquivo, modificando um campo de zero para um,  logo após feito isto volta para a pagina da tabela e muda olho de azul para vermelho e vice versa, até ai tudo bem, meu problema é o seguinte eu queria fazer exatamente este processo só que sem executar o refresh na página de modo que quando clicado ele fizesse o update e mudasse a  cor do ícone sem  a necessidade de atualizar a página, alguém saberia de que forma posso fazer isto ? [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Para não fazer refresh tem de utilizar *Ajax*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

De uma forma geral, você precisaria criar um *endpoint*/rota no seu sistema, que permite fazer a atualização que você quer passando o id e o valor do campo, e retornando se a operação foi um sucesso.
Com isso feito, você, utilizando Javascript, teria que fazer uma requisição para o *endpoint* que você criou (ao clicar no botão, claro), passando os parâmetros desejados e atualizando os elementos HTML da página conforme o resultado obtido pela requisição.